# Simple loop for making sure angle is less than 360 [Python]

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I know this is a simple problem, but I cannot get this to work. I have a list of angles, and I need them to be less than 360 degrees. How can I write a loop that will be if the angle is more than 360, to subtract 360? I tried:

```
for i in theta_degrees:
    while i>360:
        i -= 360
```

But that didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the values in-place, you need to replace the values ... in-place, not copy them to another variable:

```
for i in range(len(theta_degrees)):
    while theta_degrees[i] > 360:
        theta_degrees[i] -= 360
```

or you can use a shorter & faster & more functional approach with a list comprehension and modulo operator:

```
theta_degrees = [i % 360 for i in theta_degrees]
```

or if theta_degrees is a generator (or a very long list), you can achieve lazy evaluation using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
theta_degrees = (i % 360 for i in theta_degrees)
```

Comment: Isn't modulus much more expensive than subtraction?

Comment: not sure why you would want to compare those two - modulo produces a modulo, while subtraction produces a subtraction, which are very different operations. comparing modulo to a subtraction inside a while loop, the balance can go both ways and will depend on the distribution of input values - feel frees to do performance tests in your particular situation if your app scrapes for every microsecond, but make sure you use a decently performing compiler and not the standard CPython one..

Comment: The modulo solution is more generic, as it works for negative angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more easily with a list comprehension, and with the modulo operator instead of a `while` loop.

```
theta_degrees = [ i%360 for i in theta_degrees ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Numpy arrays, this should also work:

```
a[a >= 360] -=360
```

Comment: Good advice on numpy. `np.mod` might be better though to handle angles like 720.